# Wubi fails to install Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, wubi, lubuntu, windows-xp

```
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

That happens everytime Wubi is finished installing Lubuntu. I know there are questions like this, except I can't use a USB big enough for Lubuntu, and my PC will not work with CD/DVD drives.

The full log is too big to paste, but here's the last few lines.

```
01-20 18:07 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished get_metalink
01-20 18:07 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
01-20 18:07 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running download...
01-20 18:07 DEBUG  btdownloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent > C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Lubuntu ISO C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting .disk\info from C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Lubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin" - Release i386 (20120423)
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Lubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '12.04', 'build': '20120423', 'codename': 'Precise Pangolin', 'arch': 'i386'}
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  Distro: wrong version: 12.04 != 12.04.3
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running download...
01-20 18:28 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso > C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 18:29 DEBUG  downloader: Download start filename=C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, url=http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, basename=lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, length=721727488, text=None
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  downloader: download finished (read 721727488 bytes)
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Lubuntu ISO C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  Distro: wrong version: 12.04 != 12.04.3
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
01-20 20:05 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 600, in get_iso
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-20 20:05 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 132, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 158, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 600, in get_iso
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
01-20 20:05 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the `12.04` version of Wubi to install Lubuntu which you can find [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.0/wubi.exe).

Because Lubuntu is not an LTS (long term support), there is no `12.04.3` version, and the Wubi.exe you are running is looking for that. If you use the `12.04` version it will recognize and use the `12.04` Lubuntu ISO you've downloaded.

PS Move the file `C:\ubuntu\install\lubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` out from under `C:\ubuntu` and save it with the correct `wubi.exe` before you try to reinstall and then it won't download it all again.